# Mysql count with GROUP_CONCAT while using join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a chats table and chat_reactions table. Each chat message can have many reactions and a reaction is a text and it can be many. I am trying to return messages with the grouped reactions and the total number of times a particular reaction is used. For example,

`msg: hi with id 1` got a total of three reactions. `1 LIKE AND 2 LOVES`. How can I return it?

Here is the query I am trying

```
SELECT c.id, c.msg, GROUP_CONCAT(cr.reaction) as reaction
FROM chats as c 
LEFT JOIN chat_reactions as cr on c.id = cr.chat_id 
GROUP BY c.id
```

My result looks like this.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I add numbers with reaction or there are better and performant options I have?
Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: I would look up conditional aggregation. Assuming you have a small number of reaction types, this should be a good solution.

Comment: Could you add an example please

Comment: Do you need the output in one column (1 like 2 loves) or rather as individual columns. The conditional aggregation works great for individual columns.

Comment: Individual one if you could show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First count the post reactions. Then aggregate per post.

```
select 
  c.id,
  c.msg,
  group_concat(concat(cr.reaction, '(', cnt, ')') 
               order by cr.reaction
               separator ', ') as reactions
from chats as c 
left join 
(
  select chat_id, reaction, count(*) as cnt
  from chat_reactions 
  group by chat_id, reaction
) cr on cr.chat_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.msg
order by c.id;
```

Comment: Getting error `In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'db.c.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @HkmSadek -- see the up date -- the out select needed the group by statement.

Comment: Thanks it works. What do you think about this approach? Is there any really better ways to do unlimited types of reactions support?

Comment: @Hogan: Thank you. I had `group by c.id` and then removed it by mistake. (The group by on the id alone should suffice as the msg is functionally dependent on the primary key column.)

Comment: Unlimited? If the messages string gets too long, it will be truncated. You can alter the length limit, however. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat.

Comment: It will hold the emoji not any texts. I meant if there are different types of emojis.